# Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Unexpected error

Tags: java, xml

I am working with large scale enterprise application in java with ejb3.

I am getting xml content from database with help of below query>
SELECT CONTENT FROM TBLMXML .
and getting this content with help of below code:

```
if(rowSet.getObject("CONTENT") instanceof oracle.sql.OPAQUE){

XMLType xmlType = XMLType.createXML(((oracle.sql.OPAQUE) rowSet.getObject("CONTENT"));

}
```

But when this query fired i am getting below error:

```
14:21:15,698 : [WARN ] : [TxConnectionManager] :  Connection error occured: org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener@1357dfa[state=NORMAL mc=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@1897e13 handles=1 lastUse=1336294101874 permit=true trackByTx=true mcp=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$OnePool@9f08ca context=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool@fa3d7c xaResource=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$LocalXAResource@191a3ed txSync=null]
javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: Unexpected error
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.broadcastConnectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:409)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.connectionError(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:385)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:865)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:852)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.checkException(WrappedResultSet.java:1947)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getObject(WrappedResultSet.java:768)
    at oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet.populate(OracleCachedRowSet.java:2078)
    at com.elitecore.billingengine.ejb.base.BillingSearchSessionBase.execute(BillingSearchSessionBase.java:125)
    at com.elitecore.billingengine.ejb.billcommon.session.CacheDataProviderSessionBean.populateDataMap(CacheDataProviderSessionBean.java:196)
    at com.elitecore.billingengine.ejb.billcommon.session.CacheDataProviderSessionBean.retrieveDataQuery(CacheDataProviderSessionBean.java:158)
    at com.elitecore.billingengine.ejb.billcommon.session.CacheDataProviderSessionBean.getMapForCache(CacheDataProviderSessionBean.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor362.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386)
    at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:228)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
```

Please let me know what i am missing. ??
M using oracle 10g.

Thanks in advance

Water

Answer (score 2):

What version of JBoss are you using? I've had a very similar problem using JBoss 5 and I  solved it by doing the below:

Try having a look at your oracle-ds.xml file(it can have any name as long as it ends in *-ds.xml*). Make sure you've configured the `<min-pool-size>` as well as `<max-pool-size>` tags.

Refer to this for configuring an Oracle Datasource in JBoss 5, guide can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/Using_other_Databases.html).